# How to make 1/3 of an image take up the full screen

Tags: flutter

I have an image I want to cut up and display across multiple screens. I want 1 thrid of the image to take up the whole screen.

So far I can get 1/3 of the image to take up 1/3 of the screen with:

```
 Widget buildBGImage(String imageName) {
    return new Container(
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(border: new Border.all()),
      constraints: new BoxConstraints.expand(),
  child: new SizedBox.expand(
      child: new ClipRect(
          clipper: new WidthClipper(currentPage),
          child: new Image.asset(
              "assets/images/$imageName",
              fit: ImageFit.fill)
      )
  ),
);
```

}

```
  class WidthClipper extends CustomClipper<Rect> {
  int section;

  WidthClipper(this.section);

  @override
  Rect getClip(Size size) {
    return new Rect.fromLTWH(
        size.width * (section / 3), 0.0, size.width / 3, size.height);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(WidthClipper oldClipper) => true;
}
```

but I am drawing a bank on how to make the 1/3 take up the whole screen.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't this more a question of how to fit the image data into a fullscreen `Image`? Also, what do you want to happen if the aspect ratio of one-third-of-your-original-image does not fit the aspect ratio of the full screen?

This, for example, displays (roughly) the center third of the a landscape image in fullscreen portrait mode:

```
new Image.network(
    "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5a/Monument_Valley_2.jpg",
    fit: ImageFit.fitHeight,
    alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
)
```

While `alignment: FractionalOffset.centerLeft` and `alignment: FractionalOffset.centerRight` display (roughly) the left and right third, respectively.

Comment: I think this will work. My issue now is that using this method with pageview isn't seamless across pages.

Comment: @Mark I am very new to Flutter, too, so I am also unsure how to proceed... How would you handle the case when your source image does not cleanly split into 3 thirds that each fit a full screen? Just use more/less than 3 pages? Add padding left and right on the first and last page?

Comment: `ImageFit` was renamed to `BoxFit` 10 days after this question and answer: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/8871